# Backbone Collection filter if object is older than 30 days

Tags: backbone.js

I have a backbone collection that pulls back an array activities. And each activity has a `created_at` attribute.

When the collection is fetched, I need to filter the array of objects to only contain those who aren't older than 30 days.

The `created_at` timestamp looks like `@D:2015-02-23T08:25:49`

Answer (score 0):

As with most things Backbone, there are many ways to achieve this. One approach is to add a `validate()` method to the model. In that method return anything (convention is a string with the error description) if the model doesn't meet your criteria (i.e. if activity is too old). Then, when you fetch the collection from the server, pass the non-default option `{validate: true}` to the collection's `fetch()` method. Viola, your collection will only have recent activities.

Answer (score 0):

best way to do is using using parse method of `Collection`. This method is `executed` immediately after the data is fetched from the server.

*sample*:

```
parse: function(response) {
    // traverse through data and filter/delete the unwanted data. 
    return response.results;
  }
```

**PS:** getting unnecessary  data from the server and parsing it again dosen't seem to be optimal, if you have control over server better do this on server.